# 'with' or 'by' case studies

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

I have the following sentence:

"Section 4 demonstrates the benefits of the developed methods **with**  three case studies"

Is 'with' correct here? Or do I have to use 'by'?

I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use by instead of with....

We use by when we say what we do to get a result. 
See:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prepositions-and-particles/by

So " Section 4 demonstrates the benefits of the developed methods by three case studies"

Comment: Thanks Alka Yadav for your answer.

Comment: @PeterBe my pleasure sir..